# Remote notification is not getting

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

here is my code.

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (notification) {
        NSLog(@"app recieved notification from remote%@",notification);
        [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)notification];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"app did not recieve notification");
    }
```

When I run the app I am getting "app did not receive notification". 
That means the app is not getting remote notification. 
What can be the problem? why my app is not receving remote notification ?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use a NSDictionary, not a UILocalNotification

```
NSDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
```

Comment: yes, I have tried NSDictionary also but still app is not receving remote notification